# RTK Query: wait until all 'dependent' requests are finished

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

For example, I have this code

```
setMode(mode_name).then( start )
```

where `setMode` mutation invalidates several tags which are provided by queries `queryA`, `queryB` etc.

Is it possible to wait until not only `setMode` is finished before `start` launches but also all those other requests that are triggered on tag invalidation?
of course I can set timeout

```
setMode(mode_name).then( () => setTimeout(() => {
            start()
        }, 1000) )
```

but it doesn't guarantee anything ( `queryA`, `queryB` etc could take too long for some reason)

Comment: Am I understanding this properly?  Your `start` function uses the data from `queryA` and `queryB` and want to wait until both of those results have reloaded with new data before doing something.

Comment: I may have to think about this one a bit!  `queryA` and `queryB` will automatically reload after `setMode` invalidates their data.  You could check the `status` or `isFetching` on those queries, but I'm concerned that there will be a brief moment before they start reloading where they are still in a "success" state but with outdated data.

Comment: Linda Paiste, yes, you're right. I think using outdated data retrieved before the refetch actually happened could be avoided by making sure state has flipped from success to fetching and back. But I thought there might exist some other approach that benefits from RTK-query features